# WSO2 APIM Publish API freezing when click Next : Manage >

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Some times when I publish an API, on the Implementat fase, when I click on the Next : Manage >, the publish application freeze, I need to restart the APIM to restablishing publish application. No errors in logs.

Enviroment: RedHat EL 6.5, Java 1.7.0_80, APIM 1.9.1 with SQL Server 2008.

Thank you

Comment: You can get some more info if you enable the debug logs. Also, if there are no error logs, this can be a ui-level issue.  What is the browser you are using? Did you try with a different browser?

Comment: Yes, I tried with Firefox and Chrome, I set the log with debug, and nothing. I believed that problem is in ui-level, but only after restart apim, the publisher application is working again.

Comment: when it's stuck, are you able to access the management console or api store? otherwise the server must be hanging.

Comment: Yes, the management console and api store works normally, I believe that problem is the browser, in chrome that issues happens, but some times, in firefox happens all the time.

Comment: According to your description, the issue is definitely with the ui. You can probably try upgrading/downgrading the browser. You can track whether the request has gone from the browser to the backend by using a plugin like SSO Tracer.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I try that. Thank you.